# Porting Authenticated users to new YouTube Application

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

Say I have an application with a specific URL and API keys with 100 Authenticated YouTube users.  If wanted to rebrand the app (new URL and API keys) is it possible to have the authenticated users ported over to the new application if it can be proven it is the same offerings but with a rebranding?

Thanks,
@tedsf

Comment: Why do you need to have new API keys / a new API project? Can't you just continue to use the same one for the new app? After all, you can change an API key's URL restriction.

Comment: From my understanding when I user authenticates with 'App A' they are tied to the API keys and App ID.  If I make 'App B' I don't believe you can just start using your old API key and expect to have access to the users authenticated with 'App A'

Comment: I probably misunderstood you. When you talk about applications, i believe you mean the API projects in the cloud console, whereas i mean a website, for example. But still you could just modify the existing API project according to your needs (with new URL, name, logo, etc.). Or am I missing something?

Comment: Paolo, it's probably a lack in my understanding that is causing the confusion.  I have an online application with ~100 users that have authorized.  If I want to rebrand my application (new URL and codebase) is it possible to retain the authenticated users?  From my understanding the authenticated users are associated to the google API key connected with my application.  If I move the application I would imagine a new API key is needed and this my authenticated users would be lost..

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use a new set of Client ID / secret, then unfortunately, users will have to reauthorize with your application.